# How to serialize SOAP request objects into DB and retrieve it back?

Tags: java, oracle, serialization, soap

I am calling  a external system webservice from my java application.

There are two operations exposed in wsdl (being `invokeA` and `invokeB`)

If `invokeA` was called before with some set of request parameters next time I need to check if there is any change in the request parameter values than what it was sent in last invocation call.

If there are any changes i need to call `invokeA` again otherwise I will call `invokeB`.

I need to save the request objects in a DB and  next time before I call either `invokeA` or `invokeB` I need to compare the saved request against new  request parameters.

I am using Oracle DB and Java 7. Is there any simple way to store these objects in the DB and retrieve it back for comparison?

Comment: Normalise the invoke names and reformat

Comment: Depending on the objects, I might mark them all with `Serializable` and use `java.io.ObjectOutputStream` to serialize them to a byte array, and store that byte array in the database.

Comment: The object i want to store contains other objects as member variables. i.e. a complex objects structure and not just primitives. will I be able to retrieve same object structure from database ?